# How can I maintain login state in flutter_inappwebview after clearing cache?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-inappwebview

How can I maintain login state in flutter_inappwebview after clearing cache? "flutter_inappwebview: ^6.0.0-beta.23"
I am using the flutter_inappwebview plugin in my Flutter application to display a web page that requires authentication. I want to implement the functionality to stay logged in even after the user clears the cache.

I have tried using cookies to store the login information, but it seems that the login state is not maintained after clearing the cache. I have also verified that the website I am loading in the webview uses proper session management mechanisms.

Here is the code snippet I have tried for setting the login cookies:

dart
Copy code
// Code snippet for setting login cookies

```
`await webViewController.clearCache();
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.instance();
        Cookie? phoneNumber = await cookieManager.getCookie(
            webViewController: webViewController,
            url: WebUri("weblink"),
            name: "t1");
        Cookie? password = await cookieManager.getCookie(
            webViewController: webViewController,
            url: WebUri("weblink"),
            name: "r1");

        Debug.setLog("here is phoneNumber --> ${phoneNumber?.toJson()}");
        Debug.setLog("here is password --> ${password?.toJson()}");

        await cookieManager.setCookie(
            url: WebUri("weblink"),
            name: "t1",
            value: phoneNumber?.value,
            domain: "www.careturtle.com",
            isSecure: true,
            webViewController: webViewController);

        await cookieManager.setCookie(
            url: WebUri("weblink"),
            name: "r1",
            value: password?.value,
            domain: "www.careturtle.com",
            isSecure: true,
            webViewController: webViewController);`
```

// ...

I have also checked the documentation and examples provided by the flutter_inappwebview plugin, but I couldn't find a solution for this specific issue.

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to implement the functionality to stay logged in with flutter_inappwebview in Flutter, even after clearing the cache.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz No, It's from inAppWebView Documentation

Comment: when I use google on even just parts of the code, it doesn't find any instances, not even in official documentation. please cite those sources. pointing to the source can be generally helpful to others. https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz here it is the [link] https://inappwebview.dev/docs/cookie-manager